# What is a single word for a person who, as a habit, exaggerates a lot when relating information?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is a single word for a person who, as a habit, exaggerates a lot when relating information?

So for example, they relate something that happened but exaggerate so much that they are including clear falsehood and they are well known for doing that.

Comment: One might say [_fabulist_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/fabulist), which is a teller of [fables](http://www.wordnik.com/words/fable), but some might regard exaggeration and fables as non-equivalents, so perhaps that's not the best choice of words. If that's the case, there's always [_exaggerator_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/exaggerator).

Comment: Apparently, you are looking for something other than the obvious and natural option of *exaggerator* -- why?

Comment: *Hyperlobator*. Of course that’s a bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: George Bush called Al Gore a "serial exaggerator" leading up to the 2000 election.

Comment: I can't resist thinking that **hyperboloid** could be recoined for this...  And of course there is **fisherman** (fisherperson? fisher?).

Answer (score 13):

This kind of behavior actually is [a recognized psychiatric disorder](http://depressiond.com/pathological-liar/). Such a person is known as a *pathological liar*, a *compulsive liar*, or a *mythomaniac*. See this definition of [*pseudologia fantastica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudologia_fantastica).

Comment: Upvoted and deleted my answer-I didn't notice you'd already included *mythomaniac!*

Comment: Would this really apply to someone who just had a "**habit**" of exaggerating?  Seems a bit exaggerated... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

*[Drama Queen](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drama%20queen)*. Someone who turns something unimportant into a major deal. Someone who blows things way out of proportion when ever the chance is given.

Embroiderer, exaggerator, dramatist, fabricator, embellisher, and hyperbolist. Some dictionaries might not list the last two, but [some do](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/embellisher), such as [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hyperbolist).

Comment: @J.R.: Thank you for for the edit, J.R. I was just too lazy to do much digging.

Comment: I like your other words, especially hyperbolist, but I'm not sure a drama queen necessarily exagerates as much as simply draws attentions to him/herself about otherwise mundane issues or events.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: The definition given by the Urban Dictionary certainly suggests exaggeration: _turns something unimportant into a major deal_ and _blows things way out of proportion_. I like _hyperbolist_ too. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate term is [Bullshitter](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bullshitter) but that is definitely not polite.

A more polite way to describe them would be to say that "they tell [tall tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_tale)"

> A tall tale is a story with unbelievable elements, related as if it
>   were true and factual. Some such stories are exaggerations of actual
>   events, for example fish stories ('the fish that got away') such as,
>   "that fish was so big, why I tell ya', it nearly sank the boat when I
>   pulled it in!"

Those two terms could be more accurate than fabulist, fabricator etc as those words imply that the person making up the facts expects to be believed or believes those made up facts themselves.

If someone is telling a story, and alters the facts to make the story better, even if they know that their audience knows the true facts behind the story, they may not be trying to deceive anyone, but just to improve the story so that it is more amusing.

Answer (score 3):

*Overstater* or *braggart* could be the words you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To "spin yarns" or to be a "yarner" are two ways to describe the action and the actor of exaggeration. A "[yarn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yarn?s=t)" is a fantastic tale that carries on for the purpose of entertainment and not accuracy. It's origins, per [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=yarn&searchmode=none), are in nautical slang.

> The phrase to spin a yarn "to tell a story" is first attested 1812, from a sailors' expression, on notion of telling stories while engaged in sedentary work such as yarn-twisting.

Answer (score 0):

Histrionic. Especially if the information that is being exaggerated involves them. Anything that gets them attention though. Example: a "good friend" passed away and this person seems very distraught. In actuality, they only met the deceased person once or twice.